# Cannot set device width properly, something is sticking out

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im working responsive design on my site, but I have problem with width of the site. When you load it on mobile (I use iPhone 7) there is a white space on right side and also small horizontal scrollbar. When I open it on my notebook trough developer tools and I try to find the wide element I just cant. Its like outside HTML element.

Also iP7 should have screen width 375px, and even when I set my HTML/body max-width to 100% / 100vw I can see its 380px wide.

Here is link to site:
http://mathiashandle.infinityfreeapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, after like 2 mins of posting this question I found it -_- ....

Solution:

```
.about-col-info{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these CSS codes:

```
*{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```